# TypeError: Class constructor ErrorHandler cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm struggling with this error when I try to initialize my Node server.
Error:

```
TypeError: Class constructor ErrorHandler cannot be invoked without 'new'
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\emili\Desktop\shop\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (C:\Users\emili\Desktop\shop\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:328:13)
at C:\Users\emili\Desktop\shop\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:286:9
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\emili\Desktop\shop\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
at next (C:\Users\emili\Desktop\shop\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
at urlencodedParser (C:\Users\emili\Desktop\shop\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\urlencoded.js:91:7)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\emili\Desktop\shop\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (C:\Users\emili\Desktop\shop\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:328:13)
at C:\Users\emili\Desktop\shop\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:286:9
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\emili\Desktop\shop\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
```

Apparently, the error is related to **Express** but I don't know what should I do to solver it.
This is my ErrorHandler file:

```
class ErrorHandler extends Error {
    constructor(message, statusCode) {
        super(message);
        this.statusCode = statusCode

        Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);

    }
}
module.exports = ErrorHandler
```

and this is the way I'm importing it:

```
const express = require("express");
const ErrorHandler = require("./utils/ErrorHandler");
const app = express();

//rest of the code//

app.use(ErrorHandler);
module.exports = app;
```

Comment: `Error` isn't an error handling class, it's an exception class that's used like `throw new Error(...)`. Is that how your `ErrorHandler` class is intended to be used?

Comment: Yup! Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with Express middleware to know what you're supposed to be using here. But subclassing `Error` is probably not it.

Comment: `app.use(ErrorHandler);` makes no sense. What are you trying to achieve? Do you understand how middlewares work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your app.js, you should change this line:

```
const ErrorHandler = require("./utils/ErrorHandler");
```

TO

```
const ErrorHandler = require("./middleware/error");
```

Comment: How do you know there's a `middleware` folder in the OPs project?

Comment: B'se I happen to work on a **similar project** as his. I ran into the same issue then i realised there i was that mistake.
It came as a result of **auto importing** in my vs code.